# Keeping symbology for intersection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, intersection, point-in-polygon

I am doing a shapefile intersection (Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Intersect) to keep only the points in a point layer that overlap with the polygons in a polygon layer.

What I'd like to do is have the option to save the original point layer symbology (which has been meticulously done and will be difficult to recreate) to the resulting intersected layer. However, the intersected layer always ends up with 'default' symbology. I've been searching around for the answer to this issue, but have not found it thus far.

Any pointer? I'm using QGIS 3.18 on a Windows 10 computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the source point shapefile's Layer Properties.  In the lower-left corner click the *Style* dropdown (image below) and select *Save Style*.

Then from the intersected layer, *Load Style*, and select the saved style from above.

Voila!

[image]

Comment: Wow, that was way too easy  :)  Thanks very much for the tip, Stu Smith and wingnut.

Comment: Glad to help.  I was unaware of wingnut's idea, so it's always great to learn something new.  The methodology that I proposed creates a .qml file, which can be referred to later, even in a difference project.  Alternatively, wingnut's proposal creates (I think) a temporary, in-memory, version of the style, which is handy if you don't need the permanent version.

Comment: #Stu Smith - Once the style is pasted and the project is saved, it becomes permanent. But your method is obviously better for large projects with style requirements, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Or right click on the meticulous layer and select Styles. You can copy and paste!